# hashing the password using md5

Tags: php, mysql, logging

i want to hash the registered password in the database using MD5  and the same thing when login  but the problem is that in the register process the password get hashed but in the login  the system work as this is incorrect password

register.php

```
 //ADD MD5 hash to the password 
       $db_pass=md5($pass1);
//************Insert all the user's input to the database**************************//
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, governorate,
 district, village, birth_date, email_address, specialization, password, 
 registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$governorate',
 '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$db_pass', 
 now())") or die("could not insert data");
```

login.php

```
$pass = md5($pass);

$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name, user_name FROM user 
WHERE email_address='$email'
AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
```

Comment: Could you state more clearly what your problem is? I have no idea...

Comment: Hashing is nice, but unsalted MD5 is still pretty insecure (all unsalted hashes are vulnerable to rainbow table attacks, and MD5 in particular has been shown to be insecure).  Consider using a salted SHA2 variant instead.  Each password should have its own salt -- a global salt still allows the use of a rainbow table.

Comment: If you're just implementing this, stop now and use a proper password hashing scheme like https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat. Unsalted MD5 has been insufficient for forever now.

Comment: so how to setup a protected password  i do not have any idea else of the MD5 hash can anyone help me??

Comment: Click through to the abovelinked library and read everything, especially [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using MD5. It is insecure and it is waaaaay too fast for you to be using it for the purpose of password hashing (look at the Wiki page for [Brute-force attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) if you don't understand why using a fast password hashing algorithm is a bad idea). You should look into using something like [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

You can use Bcrypt via the [crypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

```
$userPassword = 'testpassword';
$hashed = crypt($userPassword, '$2a$15$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
echo $hashed;
```

As somebody mentioned above, ircmaxell has a [pretty good library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) available on github. The library is forwards-compatible with the password_hash function, which will be available in PHP 5.5 (currently in BETA).

Comment: i did not understand  " it is waaaaay to fast for you to be using it for the purposes of password hashing" why ???

Comment: Because MD5 is a lot faster than Blowfish, somebody with even limited hardware capabilities will be able to generate A LOT of password hashes very quickly. This means that if your database is ever exposed, it will be much easier for the attacker to hash a bunch of password attempts and then compare them with the hashes in your user table. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $pass1 and $pass are same!! Just check that, both are same before hashing.

As MD5 is insecure use sha256/sha512 with salts or use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for generating strong hashes (phpass is used by WordPress for generating password hashes).